# Any alternative of "man -a" on UNIX?

Tags: man, hp-ux

`man -a <xyz>` opens all the man pages one by one which contain `xyz`.
On my unix servers `man -a <xyz>` doesn't work.
Is there any alternative for this on unix?

EDIT:

I am on HP-UX. Following message :

```
hemantj [109]> man -a printf
Usage: man [-M path] [-T macro-package] [ section ] name ...
or: man -k keyword ...
or: man -f file ...
```

Comment: Why man -a doesn't work? Install a proper version of man. 
Try to debug it: 
strace man -a term 2> strace.out
and echo $LANG

Try to add your user to the man group.

Comment: What Unix are you exactly using: Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, *BSD? Also what does it mean "doesn't work": the `-a` option isn't recognized and man doesn't show anything or man shows only the first page? One more thing: could you give examples of `<xyz>` just to be sure that there are multiple sections on that subject?

Comment: @cristian: I just updated my original question.

Comment: what happens when you run `man printf`?

Comment: @Cristian: man printf opens man page for printf(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `man -k` work? If so, then:

```
man -k "$@" | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs man
```

might do what you want

Answer (score 2):

Is apropos available on the system? It can be used to search for man pages.

With a quick one-liner, it can come close to the `man -a` behaviour

```
man `apropos -el apt | awk -F")" '{print $1}' | awk -F"(" '{print $2, $1}'`
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But apropos not available.

Comment: `apropos` is functionally identical to (and usually implemented using) `man -k`.

Answer (score 0):

There are always emcas-based info pages:

```
$ info --apropos=man
$ info --apropos=info
```

Comment: Not necessarily (the Unix in question is HP-UX). Haven't used HP-UX since the late 90s so I don't have one handy, but GNU-based tools like `info(1)` aren't *globally* available unless we're talking about Linux. They certainly weren't available on SunOS and Solaris, and still aren't. You have to install the GNU tools separately, often by compiling them.